# firestore 1.0 not returning Firestore timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Before, my code was working well and returning `Long` value for timestamp from firestore. Since the release of firestore 1.0, the code is returning `[object Object]` as the result. Though it saves the timestamp as `June 5, 2018 at 10:38:44 AM UTC+3`meaning it is not currently saved as a `long` value in the firestore database. I have tried some possible solutions from last night but not working. Is there any solution?

```js
exports.get_time = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    // if (!request.headers.authorization) {
    //     console.error('No Firebase ID token was passed');
    //     response.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
    //     return;
    // }
    var fieldValue = require("firebase-admin").firestore.FieldValue;
    db.collection('times').doc('servertime').set({servertime: fieldValue.serverTimestamp()}).then((ref) => {
        db.collection('times').doc('servertime').get().then((snapshot) => {
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.write(String(snapshot.data()));
            response.end();
            return null;
        }).catch((error) => {
            response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.write("Error\n" + error);
            response.end();
        });
        return null;
    }).catch((error) => {
        response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("Error\n" + error);
        response.end();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem may come from the changes that were introduced in Firestore  SDK recent release (version 5.0.3 for the JavaScript SDK):

With this release the behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore changed: "timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore are read back as
Firebase Timestamp objects instead of as system Date objects."

You need to "update your code expecting a Date to instead expect a Timestamp", as follows:

```
  // Old:
  const date = snapshot.get('created_at');  // <- 'created_at' is an example of field name

  // New:
  const timestamp = snapshot.get('created_at');
  const date = timestamp.toDate();
```

---

Also, you should chain your promises a bit differently as well as change the way you send the response. You can watch the following video for more details on how to write an HTTP Function: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA

```
exports.get_time = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    var fieldValue = require("firebase-admin").firestore.FieldValue;

    db.collection('times').doc('servertime').set({servertime: fieldValue.serverTimestamp()})
        .then((ref) => {

            return db.collection('times').doc('servertime').get();

        })
        .then((snapshot) => {
            response.send(snapshot.data());
            // return null;  no need to return here since it is an HTTP Function
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            response.status(500).send(error)
        });
});
```

Comment: Am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDate' of undefined`. Is 'created_at' field treated as default or the field where I stored the timestamp? Please check my document reference in the code above in case I need to read at `Collection` level

Comment: It should be the field where you stored the timestamp. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: Appreciated, am trying the code again with that in mind

Comment: You may also watch this video from the Firebase team about HTTP Cloud Functions. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=2. You don't need to catch for the `set()` and for the `get()`. One catch is enough at the end of the promises chaining.

Comment: Great solved, I had to remove the second line since it was causing `TypeError: timestamp.toDate is not a function` and returned string version of the timestamp, I am now receiving `Tue Jun 05 2018 09:21:56 GMT+0000 (UTC)` as response. If this question may help users of the new release, please consider up-voting it.

Comment: Glad I could help! FYI I have updated my answer with an update of your Cloud Function code, changing the chaining and the way you send the response.

Comment: Thanks for the help on promise chaining.